# PSR-12 if statement

Tags: php, psr-12

Can I use if statement like:

```
if (!true) {
    return false
}
```

Or something like this:

```
if (! true) {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Pipe your code through `phpcs` with PSR-12 used as the standard and check the output.

Comment: What does PSR-12 say? What do the examples look like? In any case, you don't have to follow PSR-12 at all if you don't want to.

Comment: What does `true` represent in your question?  Is it a single variable or could it be an expression?  The answer may differ depending upon that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to PSR [example](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#example) all conditions in `if` clauses have no space before or after the expressions. In your case then

```
if (!true) {
    return false;
}
```

would be a case. Remember that with short expressions you can always use ternary operator and if you have complex condition to be checked, consider to put it into variable.

Comment: Is this classifying the ! as being a unary operator and therefore no space, although PSR-12 only specifically mentions `++` and `--`.